# Angular 2 route How to create router object in service?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have create below rest service but getting error when call this.router.navigate(['/login']); How to create router object in service? this.router.navigate is work from Component class but it's not working from service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { apiURL } from './app.config';

@Injectable()
export class RestService {
    header = new Headers();

    constructor(public http: Http, private router: Router) {


    }

    get(url: string) {
        debugger;
        this.addHeader();
        return this.http.get(apiURL + url, { headers: this.header }).catch(this.handleError);;
    }

    post(url: string, data) {
        this.addHeader();
        return this.http.post(apiURL + url, data, { headers: this.header }).catch(this.handleError);;
    }

    put(url: string, data) {
        this.addHeader();
        return this.http.put(apiURL + url, data, { headers: this.header }).catch(this.handleError);;
    }

    auth(url: string, data) {
        this.addHeader();
        return this.http.post(apiURL.replace('api/v1/', '') + '/' + url, data, { headers: this.header }).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        debugger;
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        debugger;
        if (error.status == '401') {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        else {
            let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
            console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        }
    }

    private addHeader() {
        this.header = new Headers();
        this.header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.router.navigate(['login']);` instead. The router adds the slash itself as part of the server URI.

Comment: I have debug it and this.router have nothing. I think there is issue of create object of router.